# GSAP fails to import

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, import

I am trying to include gsap into a JavaScript file and even it being very straight forward it will not load. I am using what GreenSock docs say to do and still no luck. I have added "type": "module" in the json file and the script file I am import into. In my HTML has type="module included and I have a class module already imported into it. It is working fine.

After doing a npm install gsap and it is in my .json file "gsap": "^3.11.0"

They say include this at the very top of the file using it: import {gsap} from "gsap"
Doing so only throws a console error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "gsap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I didn't include any of those being it is a npm install not a cdn script, then on a whim I did try to include any one of those and still nothing. But the error now reads:
GET ###url####ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) looking for a file in my directory. With npm install there is no file just a node_module.

Will just go to the cdn version but just wondering why this is a problem? I am using a tutorial and even the npm isntall steps he uses worked. But when I try it fails .... included image and with or with a " ./  " director included nothing loads[image]

Comment: Please post the code as text, an image.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has any advice feel free to include it here. Removed via npm remove gsap and included the cdn in my html. It is 2022 and shouldn't have to be this hard .....

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your project is local and you don't have a server (in php or node) that send the front end to your client. I have a similar problem but a little bit different. I use php so it's not directly an html file that is opened with file system but the html is rendered with a server. with my researchs i didn't find a way to directly use a npm module in your front-end without bundling your module.

You have two choice here

- You can use a CDN as @Dani_justme said but that means the client will fetch the lib from a server near from your location (if you work in local without internet connexion it is not an option).
  in your html

```html
<head>
<!-- title, meta ... -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

the gsap var is then global so you can directly use it from your modules like:

```js
//no imports
gsap.from('.text', .....)
```

- You can use the file path from the node-module folder if you work in local, if i look at your example it should be like this:

```js
import gsap from '../node-modules/gsap/index.js';
```

- if you use a server (like php or node) you need to pass your libs to the front-end, so I've seen people using bundlers like browserify to make the module accessible from your front-end but i don't know that much this approach. I recommand to search on your side how to use bundlers with your application if you need this approach.

In my case i use php and i didn't found a simple way to serve the modules so i will use CDN that is not a problem in my case.

Hope that will helps some of you guys

Answer (score -1):

I just needed to put the cdn in the html and gsap worked perfectly in the js file

```
CDN - <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
```